# "Object #<Object> has no method" fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

i'm trying to do a full synch calendar between google calendar and fullCalendar.
But right now i've a problem with date object on resize.

```
eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc,start,end) {
            alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'u'));
            // alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
            alert(
                "The end date of " + event.title + "has been moved " +
                dayDelta + " days and " +
                minuteDelta + " minutes."
            );
            // Demande la confirmation du redimenssionnement 
            if (!confirm("Confirmation la modification?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },
```

So i'm sure that i do something wrong ...

calendrier.js :

```
/* 
 * Mise en forme du calendrier et des différentes fonctions / interactions avec 
 * celui ci
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // Chargement des énévements depuis le calendrier google
        events: {
            // calendrier partager en public
            url : 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/riat.tom%40gmail.com/public/basic',
            editable: true       
        },

        // Entete du calendrier
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        // Vue par défaut mise en semaine
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        // Permet de sélectionner les events
        selectable: true,

        // Aide à la sélection
        selectHelper: true,

        // Rend le calendrier éditable
        editable: true,

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Lors d'une sélection d'une plage on propose un ajout avec entré de titre
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        select: function(start, end) {
            // Recois un texte entré
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            // Création de l'évenement dans un format de date ISO8601 UTC
            if(title != '' && title != null){
                createEvent(
                        title, 
                        $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 'T' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'HH:mm:ss.000+01:00'),    
                        $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 'T' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'HH:mm:ss.000+01:00')
                );
            }


            // on enleve la sélection pour laisser place à l'évenement
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

            // On actualise le calendrier en rappelant toutes les sources
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        },
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Après un drag'n'drop d'un évenement
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
            alert(
                event.title + " was moved " +
                dayDelta + " days and " +
                minuteDelta + " minutes."
            );

            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }

        },

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Après une modification de temps d'intervention
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc,start,end) {
            alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'u'));
            // alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
            alert(
                "The end date of " + event.title + "has been moved " +
                dayDelta + " days and " +
                minuteDelta + " minutes."
            );
            // Demande la confirmation du redimenssionnement 
            if (!confirm("Confirmation la modification?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // ouverture d'une popup lors du clic sur l'évenement
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        eventClick: function(calEvent) {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Suppression de l'évenement au clic
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /*
            deleteEvent(calEvent.title);
            // Empeche la redirection vers le calendrier google
            if (!confirm("Confirmation la modification?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            */

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Modification de l'évenement au clic
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var newEvent = prompt('Entrer un nouveau nom');
            editEvent('test a', newEvent);

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test calendrier</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' media="" type='text/css' href='css/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/gcal.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/account.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/event.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/calendrier.js'></script>

    <!-- <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAEobLGDxmyE-A9YknRQOjkBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxRAbim8Zaj8QsHGwbTcqgYmr1rXlg" type="text/javascript"></script>
    Clé localhost -->
     <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAEobLGDxmyE-A9YknRQOjkBRBSQP7kN3nJ0TG1omTe6BwHiHeOBSf0Z4zFlArCAZ6g9Hu-lT6VojEeQ" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Récupération des données utilisateurs
        google.load("gdata", "1")
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' /> <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 1</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 2</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 3</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 4</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 5</div>


    <div id="calendar" style="width:900px; margin: 0 px auto;"></div>
    <img src="images/any.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:-10000px;" />

    <input type="button" value="Affiche Event private" onclick="alert(retriveEvent())" />
    <input type="button" value="login" onclick="getMyFeed();" />
    <input type="button" value="info" onclick="alert(doCheck());" />
    <input type="button" value="logout" onclick="doLogout();" />
    <input type ="button" value="refresh" onclick="$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );" />
    <input type="button" value="affiche date" />

    <div id="val"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what language? tag properly please.

Comment: If you come up with the answer to your question on your own, post it as an answer (the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom) rather than editing the answer into the question.

Comment: I've upvoted you for your answer. But provide an answer as a separate answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was wrong.

The answer is that i used the bad object. I tried to use "start" instead of "event"

well the good code is this one :

```
eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
        alert(event.start);
        alert(event.end);
        /*
        alert(
            "The end date of " + event.title + "has been moved " +
            dayDelta + " days and " +
            minuteDelta + " minutes."
        );
        */
        // Demande la confirmation du redimenssionnement 
        if (!confirm("Confirmation la modification?")) {
            revertFunc();
        } else {
            alert(event.title);
            alert('event édité');
        }
    },
```